# Sealing the base of a metal-sided building built on a slab

Tags: concrete, waterproofing, metal

The store we own is old. The original building is 100+ years - but the problem we're facing today is a stick-frame metal-sided addition (lean-to, 3 sides attached to the original building). This large shed is useful to us, but it was built on a flat concrete slab that was not graded properly, so the water doesn't drain fast enough to the road edge. The result is that water gets under the walls and floods inside after hard rain or a hard melt.

If there isn't a magic "Through the Roof" kind of goo that will anneal to metal, concrete, and if it happens to be exposed enough, wood, to block the water, that would last longer than one year (is there?), what would I need to do if I removed the metal siding to seal the building?

Comment: How about some pictures of the inside & outside of the walls showing where they meet the concrete. It will help people have a better idea of what's going on. I was with you until you got to "magic through the roof" because usually, one doesn't go through the roof to address an issue at the slab.

Comment: @FreeMan I'll get some pictures. My statement was in regard to a product, a caulk called "[Through the Roof](https://www.sashco.com/products/through-the-roof/)," which is often used to seal leaks.